# Delete related records before delete trigger postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I need to make trigger, which will delete related rows in related table. Yes, I know about ON DELETE CASCADE, but the thing is I need to do it using trigger. I google it for several hours, but don't find solution for Postgesql. I use postgresql 9.4, pgAdmin III.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Customer"
(
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "ContactPerson" text NOT NULL,
    "Address" text NOT NULL,
    "PhoneNumber" "PhoneNumber" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "CustomerId (PK)" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE "Order"
(
    "Id" serial NOT NULL,
    "OrderDate" date NOT NULL DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
    "Amount" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "CustomerId" integer NOT NULL,
    "GoodId" integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "OrderId (PK)" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "CustomerId (FK)" FOREIGN KEY ("CustomerId")
        REFERENCES "Customer" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "GoodId (FK)" FOREIGN KEY ("GoodId")
        REFERENCES "Good" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "AmountCheck" CHECK ("Amount" > 0),
    CONSTRAINT "OrderDateCheck" CHECK ("OrderDate" <= 'now'::text::date)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I create trigger using this query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteCustomerWithOrders() RETURNS trigger AS $DeleteCustomerWithOrders$
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM "Order"
        WHERE "Order"."CustomerId" = (SELECT "Id" FROM "Customer");
        RETURN "Customer";        
    END;
$DeleteCustomerWithOrders$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER DeleteCustomerWithOrders BEFORE DELETE ON "Customer"
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE DeleteCustomerWithOrders();
```

The query runs well, but then I try to delete row from `Customer`, it gets an error:

[image: column "Customer" does not exists]

(column "Customer" does not exists)

There is only examples of ON INSERT or UPDATE triggers in documentation, there they use `RETURN NEW`. Also I saw using `OLD` in sql-server. Nothing of it helps in my case. Also there may be errors in `WHERE`.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Patrick. This solves first problem, but causes another one.

[image: another problem]

Error: record `old` does not assigned value. Detail: for not assigned record cortege structure is not defined.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it. It also would be better if you post the error messages in English (set `lc_messages=English`)

Comment: `lc_messages=English` I should write it in script or in pgAdmin settings? Sorry, don't understand, what do you mean "dreaded quoted identifiers", my function name?

Answer (score 4):

You have two small problems with your code.

The trigger runs on table `"Customer"` but in the trigger function you refer to the row of this table being deleted with the pre-defined parameter `OLD`. Also, do not select the `id` from that row, but just refer to it (the sub-query actually retrieves all the `id`s from the table, which is wrong too).

The trigger function should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteCustomerWithOrders() RETURNS trigger AS
$DeleteCustomerWithOrders$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM "Order"
    WHERE "Order"."CustomerId" = OLD."Id";
    RETURN OLD;        
END;
$DeleteCustomerWithOrders$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error you received comes from the statement `RETURN "Customer";`. The RETURN statement expects a `trigger` parameter but find an identifier. The system then interprets this as a SELECT statement that will return a `trigger` object but the statement is obviously incomplete: `"Customer"` is in the select list and thus interpreted as a column name, but there is no row source (`FROM ...`) to complete the statement and it can thus not resolve the column name.

Comment: Unfortunately this solves problem on the screenshot, causes to another one. Please look update in first massage.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the trigger function, as far as I can tell. Are you maybe calling this function directly (e.g. not automatically on DELETE but  manually)?

Comment: No, I was deleting it using either table data view or `DELETE FROM`. In both case I got this error.